Multiply polars columns of number type with object type (which supports __mul__)
I have the following code.
import polars as pl

class Summary:
    def __init__(self, value: float, origin: str):
        self.value  = value
        self.origin = origin

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'Summary({self.value},{self.origin})'

    def __mul__(self, x: float | int) -> 'Summary':
        return Summary(self.value * x, self.origin)

    def __rmul__(self, x: float | int) -> 'Summary':
        return self * x

mapping = {
    'CASH':  Summary( 1, 'E'),
    'ITEM':  Summary(-9, 'A'),
    'CHECK': Summary(46, 'A'),
}

df = pl.DataFrame({'quantity': [7, 4, 10], 'type': mapping.keys(), 'summary': mapping.values()})

The dataframe df looks as follows.
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────────┬───────┬───────────────┐
│ quantity ┆ type  ┆ summary       │
│ ---      ┆ ---   ┆ ---           │
│ i64      ┆ str   ┆ object        │
╞══════════╪═══════╪═══════════════╡
│ 7        ┆ CASH  ┆ Summary(1,E)  │
│ 4        ┆ ITEM  ┆ Summary(-9,A) │
│ 10       ┆ CHECK ┆ Summary(46,A) │
└──────────┴───────┴───────────────┘

Especially, the summary column contains a Summary class object, which supports multiplication. Now, I'd like to multiply this column with the quantity column.
However, the naive approach raises an error.
df.with_columns(pl.col('quantity').mul(pl.col('summary')).alias('qty_summary'))

SchemaError: failed to determine supertype of i64 and object

Is there a way to multiply these columns?

Usually, you'd avoid having columns of type object in your dataframe as no native polars operation can be applied. Would it be an option to store the Summary objects as a struct with fields value and origin?

The reason I tried to use a Summary object (which is much bigger in my real code) is that i have some fields that need to be multiplied like value and some that do not like origin. So ideally, I keep the Summary object so i don't need to manually pick the subset of columns that need to be multiplied.

I think it's possible to do with map_elements() but I think applying OOP to polars dataframes is a bit of a wrong direction - you're not be able to benefit from vectorization

@RomanPekar I think its not straightforward to apply map_elements() out of the box. You'd need to a apply it on a struct column (allowing you to access the multiplicative factor), but all struct fields must have a valid polars dtype.

I see, so perhaps I could use 2 struct columns: one for the fields that can be multiplied and the other for the fields for which multiplication does not apply?

You don't even need a struct column. Just store the data in regular columns and have a list of column names to which to apply the multiplication.

Remember that Polars is designed so that computations run in Rust, not Python, where it's like 1000x faster. If you have Python operations you want to run, you lose a lot of the benefit of using Polars in the first place.
But, thankfully, Polars does have a very nice feature that is relevant here, which is “native” processing of dataclasses.
import polars as pl
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Summary:
    value: float
    origin: str

    def __mul__(self, x: float | int) -> "Summary":
        return Summary(self.value * x, self.origin)

    def __rmul__(self, x: float | int) -> "Summary":
        return self * x


mapping = {
    "CASH": Summary(1, "E"),
    "ITEM": Summary(-9, "A"),
    "CHECK": Summary(46, "A"),
}

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "quantity": [7, 4, 10],
        "type": mapping.keys(),
        "summary": mapping.values(),
    }
)

df

Because Summary is a dataclass, you 1. don't need __init__ and __repr__ (they come for free), and 2. don't need to do anything special for Polars to struct-ify them.
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────────┬───────┬────────────┐
│ quantity ┆ type  ┆ summary    │
│ ---      ┆ ---   ┆ ---        │
│ i64      ┆ str   ┆ struct[2]  │
╞══════════╪═══════╪════════════╡
│ 7        ┆ CASH  ┆ {1.0,"E"}  │
│ 4        ┆ ITEM  ┆ {-9.0,"A"} │
│ 10       ┆ CHECK ┆ {46.0,"A"} │
└──────────┴───────┴────────────┘

Now you can just do regular Polars struct ops:
df.with_columns(
    qty_summary=pl.struct(
        pl.col("summary").struct.field("value") * pl.col("quantity"),
        pl.col("summary").struct.field("origin"),
    )
)


I didn't know about the out-of-the-box dataclass support. It's awesome!

You mentioned in the comments that you'd like to be able to multiply certain fields of Summary column by another column.
Maybe as a suggestion you could store your data as a Struct:
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "type": ["CASH","ITEM","CHECK"], 
    "summary": [{'value':  1.0, 'origin': 'E'}, {'value': -9.0, 'origin': 'A'},  {'value': 46.0, 'origin': 'A'}],
    "quantity": [7,4,10]
})

┌───────┬────────────┬──────────┐
│ type  ┆ summary    ┆ quantity │
│ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---      │
│ str   ┆ struct[2]  ┆ i64      │
╞═══════╪════════════╪══════════╡
│ CASH  ┆ {1.0,"E"}  ┆ 7        │
│ ITEM  ┆ {-9.0,"A"} ┆ 4        │
│ CHECK ┆ {46.0,"A"} ┆ 10       │
└───────┴────────────┴──────────┘

And just separately define a list of fields which you want to be affected. You can use with_fields() to multiply some of the fields of the struct:
fields_to_multiply = ["value"]

df.with_columns(
    pl.col.summary.struct.with_fields(
        pl.field(fields_to_multiply) * pl.col.quantity
    )
)


┌───────┬─────────────┬──────────┐
│ type  ┆ summary     ┆ quantity │
│ ---   ┆ ---         ┆ ---      │
│ str   ┆ struct[2]   ┆ i64      │
╞═══════╪═════════════╪══════════╡
│ CASH  ┆ {7.0,"E"}   ┆ 7        │
│ ITEM  ┆ {-36.0,"A"} ┆ 4        │
│ CHECK ┆ {460.0,"A"} ┆ 10       │
└───────┴─────────────┴──────────┘

